# Need a script for each subdirectory to execute a command if a matching subdirectory is found

Tags: powershell

I'm interested in using Powershell with robocopy but I am to of a n00b to figure out everything on my own.  If someone is bored, by all means take a crack at this.  If im violating some rule, im sorry in advance.

I have a bunch of subfolders as:

```
C:\AB1234_randomadfasdf
C:\AB1234_otherrandomds
c:\AB1235_randomasdfgfd
C:\AB1236_randomsdfgsdf
```

For each of those folders, If a matching (folder below) is found ONLY:

```
D:\AB1234
D:\AB1235
D:\AB1236
```

I want to execute a robocopy command like

```
robocopy C:\AB1234_randomadfasdf D:\AB1234\AB1234_randomadfasdf /e /z 
robocopy C:\AB1234_otherrandomds D:\AB1234\AB1234_otherrandomds /e /z 
etc
```

Comment: You can take a look on the documentation how to use Regexp in Powershell : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6

Comment: Good explanation here for -match and other methods : https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/

Comment: [1] get the source dir list via `Get-ChildItem` [2] get the target dir list via the same cmdlet [3] iterate thru the SourceDIr collection via something like `foreach` [4] split the SorceDirName via `.Split()` or `-split` [5] use the result to find if there is a match in the TargetDir collection [6] if a match is found, use the SourceDir & TargetDir as inputs for your Robocopy call [7] finish iterating ///// that seems to cover the outline. if you get stuck, post your code, and what seems to be failing so folks can discuss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will check if any folder from source containing an underscore
and splitted there - is present in destination and invoke robocopy:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\22\SO_53891986.ps1

$src = 'C:\'
$dst = 'D:\'

Get-ChildItem "$src*_*" -Directory | 
  Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^(.*?)_' -and (Test-Path (Join-Path $dst $Matches[1]))} |
    ForEach-Object {
      &robocopy $_.FullName ("{0}{1}\{2}" -f $dst,$Matches[1],$_.Name) /e /z
    }
```

Sample tree after running the script with same $src and $dst

```
> tree \
├───AB1234
│   ├───AB1234_otherrandomds
│   └───AB1234_randomadfasdf
├───AB1234_otherrandomds
├───AB1234_randomadfasdf
├───AB1235
│   └───AB1235_randomasdfgfd
├───AB1235_randomasdfgfd
├───AB1236
│   └───AB1236_randomsdfgsdf
└───AB1236_randomsdfgsdf
```

Comment: thank you it works, i'll decode each command to learn exactly what you did.  thanks!!